# Password mask for CVV number in stripe card element

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments

I would like to set the password mask for `CVV` number in Stripe `card element`. I have explored [Stripe js](https://stripe.com/docs/js/elements_object/create_element?type=card) documentation but I couldn't find the way to set the password mask for `CVV` number.

This is how I am trying to achieve

[image: Stripe card element]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Doesn't seem like there's a way to do it with stripe v3, though you can set a custom class through the `elements.create` - you can then do something like `document.querySelector('input.yourCustomClass').type = "password"` on page ready / element creation

Comment: "Most online checkout forms don't mask out the CVC number. The PCI and other appropriate standards also don't recommend doing so". taken from an issue on github: https://github.com/stripe/react-stripe-elements/issues/328